# Issue in TestNG with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have tried with the below url in Eclipse to install the TestNG Plugin..

```
Select Help / Install new software. 
Search for new features to install. 
New remote site. 
For Eclipse 3.4 and above, enter http://beust.com/eclipse. 
For Eclipse 3.3 and below, enter http://beust.com/eclipse1.
```

But Unfortunately Both gets Connection refused..

I have downloaded the files from https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/

When I extract the zip, It has the following things:

```
Scripts, 
testng-eclipse-feature, 
testng-eclipse-plugin, 
testng-eclipse-Update-Site, 
.cvsignore, 
.gitignore,
.project,
.travel.yml,
changes.log,
new-release,
pom.xml,
README.md
```

I have copied features and plugin and pasted in the eclipse feature and plugin folder respectively. Now If i create TestNG class,

I am getting following error "The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.testng.eclipse was unable to load class org.testng.eclipse.wizards.NewTestNGClassWizard.
org.testng.eclipse.wizards.NewTestNGClassWizard"

Can any one help on this??

Thanks

Comment: Did you try installing from eclipse market place?? please give it a try. if not please specify whether you are using eclipse luna or not?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno.. Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of Eclipse, please upgrade to Luna and give it a try it would certainly work.

1)First try the same method of yours from install new software.

2)Go to Eclipse Market place and just type TestNG and search, it would display the plugin and install it.